# javascript Filter / Search Html List

Tags: javascript

this is a simple program for searching an item from html list it works perfect but how can make it more advanced by adding few lines of codes to display a message like nothing was found or no result found if input didn't match an item from a list ?

```js
function myFunction(){
    let input = document.getElementById('myInput').value.trim();
    let ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    let li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    let anch = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    let res = document.getElementById('result');
    for(let i = 0 ; i < anch.length ; i++){
       if(anch[i].innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1){
           anch[i].style.display="";
           anch[i].style.color="red";
       }else{
           anch[i].style.display="none";
       }
     }
    }
```

```css
<style>
      #myInput {
      background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png'); /* Add a search icon to input */
      background-position: 10px 12px; /* Position the search icon */
      background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the icon image */
      width: 100%; /* Full-width */
      font-size: 16px; /* Increase font-size */
      padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px; /* Add some padding */
      border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
      margin-bottom: 12px; /* Add some space below the input */
    }

    #myUL {
      /* Remove default list styling */
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    #myUL li a {
      border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a border to all links */
      margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
      background-color: #f6f6f6; /* Grey background color */
      padding: 12px; /* Add some padding */
      text-decoration: none; /* Remove default text underline */
      font-size: 18px; /* Increase the font-size */
      color: black; /* Add a black text color */
      display: block; /* Make it into a block element to fill the whole list */
    }
    #myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
      background-color: #eee; /* Add a hover effect to all links, except for headers */
    }
    </style>
```

```html
<html lang="en-US">
      <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=0.1,shrink-to-fit=no">
         <link type="text/css" href="/css" rel="stylesheet">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <title>Search</title>
             </head>
              <body>
               <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">
                <ul id="myUL">
                 <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
                 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a variable to know if there were coincidences at the end of the loop.

```
var somethingFound=false;
...
for(let i = 0 ; i < anch.length ; i++){
   if(anch[i].innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1){
       ...
       somethingFound=true; //or somethingFound++ if you wan to keep a count
   } else {
       ...
   }
}
document.querySelector("#nothingFoundMessage").style.display=somethingFound?"block":"none"; //or something similar
```